# Connecting to MongoDB replica set with rmongodb

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb

Has anyone been able to connect to a MongoDB replica set using `rmongodb`? No matter how I configure `mongo.create` I get an authentication error, even though the same host/username/password work fine when connecting via the `mongo` shell.

My code does the equivalent of:

```
> mongo.create(c("rs-1.mysite.com:12345","rs-2.mysite.com:12345"), "rsName", "user", "password", "my_db")
Unable to connect to replset
Authentication failed.
```

**Update:**

Looking at the logs of all the nodes in the replica set, I do not see any attempt to authenticate when I run the code above. Therefore, this may be a `rmongodb` bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sim has noted, [rmongodb 1.0.3 does not resolve hostnames](https://github.com/gerald-lindsly/rmongodb/issues/6).

It is, however, possible to connect to replica sets from rmongodb with with a few caveats:

- you must include all hostnames (if the primary isn't found in the seed host list, rmongodb will fail to connect)
- hostnames must be provided as IPs
- if using an admin user, you must first auth to the admin database (this, at least, is [expected behaviour](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication#SecurityandAuthentication-Logginginasanadminuser) but worth noting)
- I could only get the connection to work by *not* providing a replSet name

So my working connect string looks like:

```
mongo.create(c("192.168.1.123:27017","192.168.1.124:27018","192.168.1.125:27017"),"","user","password", "thedb")
```

NB: I only tested this with MongoDB 2.2.0.

Comment: For what it's worth, I was able to use a URI's instead of IP's.

Comment: @SteveO7 This answer was from several years ago. Replica support has been added since then ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the C source, it seems that `rmongodb` does not resolve hostnames into IP addresses. The only way this works is if you pass an IP address string to the driver...

By passing an IP address and port number you can connect to one of the nodes. I still cannot get `rmongodb` to successfully connect to a replica set.

Comment: Did you finally manage to connect to MongoDB with a Replica Set using rmongodb? I am stuck with the same problem

Comment: I built my own driver wrapper library around `rmongodb`. I haven't had the time to package it up and add it to CRAN.

Comment: can we connect hostName instead of IP address?

Comment: @RahulSaini sure