# Unable to see all collections from a MongoDB remote server using mongolite

Tags: r, mongolite

This may be a trivial problem. I'm able to connect to remote MongoDB server. Im using mongolite for connecting to the db. My DB is mobileapps. I also don't know what to specify in 'collection'. I know I can specify any collection.

```
library(mongolite)
con=mongo(collection = "test", url = "mongodb://user:password@ds035965.mongolab.com:35965/mobileapps")
```

Though it is connecting, but doesn't show any data. Also I don't understand why does it show this for str(con): why is jeroen there.

```
Classes 'mongo', 'jeroen', 'environment' <environment: 0x0000000014a8ec00>
```

It is connecting but I am unable to see all the collections. How do I see all the collections in the db.

Also how do some basic statistics about the collection without querying like column names, types. I could only use con$count() to count the rows in the db. Something similar to db.getCollectionNames() from cmd prompt.

**Update 1**

I understand that I have to specify a particular collection while connecting from mongolite. But how do I connect using Rmongodb is still an issue.

```
mongo.create(host = "ds035965.mongolab.com", name = "MobileApp1", username = "user", password = "password ", db = "mobileapps")
```

This gives me an error:

```
Unable to connect to replset
Authentication failed.
```

**Update 2**

When I connect to my local host using **rmongodb** I get this error.

```
Error in as.environment(pos) : invalid 'pos' argument
```

Even though I'm able to see the db and the collection within, I still get this error. Any thoughts on what's happening?

Comment: `jeroen` is a **class** defined by the package author, Jeroen Ooms. See line 261 of the [source code](https://github.com/jeroenooms/mongolite/blob/master/R/object.R)

Comment: reading another [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12233874/5977215), it could be that you need to use an IP address, not a host name?

Comment: @Symbolix: That would mean i would not be able to connect with out any ip right.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain, and haven't researched it in great detail, but appears that you need an ip for `rmongodb`

Comment: @Symbolix: Me too. Thanks for your help!\

Comment: You should note that `rmongodb` has been [removed from cran](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmongodb/index.html) and is [no longer supported/maintained](https://github.com/dselivanov/rmongodb/issues/96)

Comment: @SymbolixAU oh thats sad news. will look for other package then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**mongolite** requires you to connect to a specific collection of a database. When you initialise the `mongo` object, you see that the `db` and `collection` arguments default to "test"

```
?mongolite::mongo
```

> mongo(collection = "test", db = "test", url = "mongodb://localhost", verbose = TRUE)

Therefore, when you initialise `con` with

```
con=mongo(collection = "test", url = "mongodb://user:password@ds035965.mongolab.com:35965/mobileapps")
```

Even though you haven't specified it to connect to a particular database, it is connecting to **`db = test`**, because that is the default. And, therefore, if you don't have a database called **test**, it won't contain any data. Which explains why you're not seeing any data.

---

It's my understanding (and I'm happy to be corrected) that with `mongolite` it's not possible to look at all the collections in a database, as you have to specifically connect to one.

If you want to see the collections, you can try the `rmongodb` package

```
library(rmongodb)
mongo <- mongo.create()
mongo.get.databases(mongo)
## returns databases
```

However, to see all the collections in the database you can't use the function

```
mongo.get.database.collections(mongo, "test")
```

as it return an empty string. This is a [known issue](https://github.com/mongosoup/rmongodb/issues/93)

A workaround is to use

```
## return all the collections in the database 'test'
mongo.command(mongo = mongo, db = "test", command = list(listCollections=1))

mongo.destroy(mongo)
```